# Profile Eclipse RCP with VisualVM

Tags: java, profiling, eclipse-rcp, visualvm

I am developing an application based on Eclipse RCP. I want to profile specific methods in my application: dropping an element and refreshing sections.

I successfully connected VisualVM launch plugin to Eclipse. After my application ran I executed Profiler from VisualVM and dragged/refreshed some stuff in the application being profiled. At the end, I did not see corresponding methods in the call stack. I cannot find any methods which are responsible for my stuff and I can't do anything.

Why does this happen? If I run VisualVM before the whole application starts - everything seems to be ok. Each method has the correct place in the call stack. I am curious about VisualVM limitations.

Comment: Are you sure you are profiling your developed application, and not your Eclipse IDE environment?

Comment: This is not related to your problem with VisualVM, but I found the JVM Monitor Eclipse plugin extremely helpful: http://jvmmonitor.org. It allows you to monitor your RCP application directly in Eclipse and has quite some nice features.

Comment: Is that caused by OSGi class loadding mechanism?