# Java Eclipse RCP Profiler

Tags: java, eclipse, profiling, performance-testing

I'd like to profile my Eclipse RCP application.

In the past I've used [JVM Monitor](http://jvmmonitor.org/), but this does not seem compatible with the latest version of Eclipse (>4.9) - it's a shame because this worked really well within Eclipse.

I've tried [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/), which looks ok - but doesn't appear to work with RCP applications when I tried (and it seems I'm not [the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14607634)).

So - what is the most popular (free) profiler that I could be using? I need to be able to break down timings by methods.

Thanks!

Comment: The other one you mentioned stated _"If I run VisualVM before the whole application starts - everything seems to be ok."_ What is preventing you from starting VisualVM before your RCP application?

Comment: @howlgler - when I tried this I couldn’t get it work, it didnt seem to able to connect to the application - but I didn’t test it exhaustively. I’ve since tried JProfiler - which works - but isn’t free...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since tried VisualVM again and it does appear to work with RCP applications IF you start it first. It's a shame it's not integrated closer to Eclipse, but it gives me the answers I need.